# Looking for a JS framework that works outside browser and node

Tags: javascript, applescript, javascript-automation

I am looking for a JavaScript framework that works without a browser, and
without Node. I need a system to organise some JS AppleScripts that are growing
in size, so I am looking for something like AngularJS's factories, services,
etc.

Because I am only looking for a small part of something like AngularJS, I would
have no problem trying to make one myself. I'm sure it will be a lot of fun :).
But is there anything out there that already exists?

Answer (score -1):

I just found this website http://microjs.com/ which seems really good for finding tiny frameworks. I am still deciding which framework to choose (searching under "module"). Will edit once I choose